# Relational Mapping between two Dynamic Amounts of Entities

Tags: sql, relational-database

I have two amounts of dynamic entities. For example
B1, B2, B3, B4, B5,... I don't know how many B's i have but i will have a specific table in SQL for each B. On the other hand i have a dynamic amount of A's each represented as a single row in Table AEnum.

Now i want to have a Mapping. The mapping looks like that:
Each a can have each entity of B or not => 1/0 => boolean.

For example:

```
A1 => B1 (true), B2 (true), B3 (false), B4 (true)...
A2 => B1 (true), B2 (false), B3 (false), B4 (true)...
A3 => B1 (false), B2 (true), B3 (true), B4 (true)...
```

So for each B i made a column with B's name in the Table AHasB, just storing a tinyint. This is however not very dynamic. I want to make it as dynamic as possible.

Possible idea:
Table BEnum stores Bid and BName (the Tablename of B's instance), AEnum stays the same just being a number of rows storing stuff about each A. Then AHasB would look like:

```
A1 => "B1, B4, B12"
A2 => "B9, B10"
```

Just storing it as a single string which i parse on the logic side, not the persistence side. With that solution the following would be the case:

- When adding a B: I only need to add the B table manually and update the BEnum table
- When deleting a B: Delete the table, update the BEnum table accordingly and update AHasB to delete all B instances out of the strings that just have been deleted
- When adding a A: Just insert a new row in AHasB
- When deleting an A: Just remove that row

I think that would be the most dynamic approach. Or is there any better way to save this in a SQL database?

If anyone asks: B1, B2, B3,... are all names for quite different tables. For example: cars, hobbys, etc. A1, A2, A3, are persons and the relation can be read as "For person X i want to know which hobbies he has, what cars he drives, etc."

Someone any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can represent a relation between any entity sets as a table containing a column for each entity set.  For example:

```
persons (person PK, name, age, ...)
cars (car PK, make, model, ...)
car_owners (person PK/FK, car PK/FK)
```

In car_owners, including both columns in the PK ensures the pair is unique, meaning a many-to-many relation.  Limiting the PK to the one or other means entities in that column are required to be unique, hence a one-to-many relation.